# Css em todas as options com exceção de uma

Tags: css, css3

Estou tentando aplicar um css em uma tag option. No caso gostaria que somente as opcões que possuem *value* começando com 2 ficassem em azul, como o exemplo abaixo:

```js
$('.select-user option').each(function(){
  if(this.value.startsWith('2')){
    $(this).addClass('option-blue')
  }
})
```

```css
.select-user{
  width: 200px;
}

.option-blue{
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="user" class="select-user">
  <option value="1-000">Rosa</option>
  <option value="2-004">José</option>
  <option value="1-001">Maria</option>
  <option value="1-003">Ana</option>
  <option value="2-005">Pedro</option>
  <option value="2-005">Matheus</option>
</select>
```

No entanto, nesse exemplo, estou adicionando a classe na tag *option* diretamente no html. Como eu poderia selecionar as opções usando apenas CSS, sem o código em javascript?

Comment: Se é você mesmo que gera a option (manualmente ou automaticamente), não seria só gerar a classe correspondente no mesmo momento? Se está fazendo o html "na mão", basta por um `class="comdois"` nas desejadas, se está gerando via programação (PHP, C#, seja lá o que for) basta por essa lógica de "if começado por dois ponha classe tal" no loop que gera as opções, não? Evitaria depender do usuário final para isso. Ou, use CSS puro em vez de JS, se é só o 2 inicial que determina, nem precisa de JS.

Comment: Cara faz sentido, eu estava procurando uma forma com css, para diminuir parte do código.

Comment: Essa solução postada abaixo, do colega WallaceMaxters é muito boa, resolve com CSS puro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assim?

```css
.select-user{
  width: 200px;
}

.select-user > option[value^="2"]{
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
 
<select name="user" class="select-user">
  <option value="1-000">Rosa</option>
  <option value="2-004">José</option>
  <option value="1-001">Maria</option>
  <option value="1-003">Ana</option>
  <option value="2-005">Pedro</option>
  <option value="2-005">Matheus</option>
</select>
```

O trecho `option[value^="2"]` indica que todos os elementos cujo o atributo `value` comece por `2` serão marcados com o estilo determinado ali.

O `^=` tem o mesmo efeito que a função `String.startsWith` do Javascript.

Sugiro dar uma olhada nessa pergunta do [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338680/is-there-a-css-selector-by-class-prefix)

O nome disso é [Attribute Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) e está disponível a partir do CSS 3.

Comment: Vlw, era isso mesmo.